# Scalatra location for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scala, angularjs, scalatra

I generated a Scalatra project using the standard instructions (using giter8).

I've created a AngularJS frontend with an index.html that I've placed at WEB-INF/views/index.html. It can see the html, but I can't get Scalatra to see the javascript.

I'm routing to the html using:

```
get("/") {
  contentType="text/html"
  new java.io.File(servletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/views/index.html").getFile)
}
```

Currently the javascript and bower stuff is sitting in a subfolder of the views folder. How do I get Scalatra to use it?

Comment: Oops. I figured it out.
You have to place the folder of javascript files right into webapp, which is the folder that contains WEB-INF

Comment: you can answer your own question.

Comment: When I tried to answer it:
"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking."  :-\